# TRUNCATE locked by Select pg_proc

Tags: postgresql

The TRUNCATE of a table does not pass because of the following lock:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE "public"."xxxxx" | SELECT DISTINCT x.oid,x.* FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc x 
WHERE x.proname ILIKE X 
AND x.proname NOT LIKE '\_%' 
AND x.pronamespace IN (Y,Z) 
ORDER BY x.proname 
LIMIT 10
```

Thank You for your help
Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

No, that query didn't lock the table. It was a previous statement running in the same transaction as the `SELECT`.

Comment: The Truncate has been blocked and when we have killed the process which launches, the SELECT, the truncate has finished successfuly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would expect. But the problematic lock on `"public"."xxxxx"` was certainly *not* taken by a query on `pg_proc`, but by an earlier query in the same transaction.